# Get list of all unattached content databases

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

We have few content dbs which are not attached to SharePoint. I want to get list of all content databases which are unattached...I got a powershell command

```
 `"Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase -DatabaseServer SERVER\SQL1 -DatabaseName DBNAME"`.
```

But this requires me to enter db name which I want to list down. Is there a way to get the list?

Comment: you can get all the content databases  with the below loop :#Get all SharePoint content databases available
$ContentDatabases = Get-SPContentDatabase
#Loop through each content database
 foreach($ContentDb in $ContentDatabases)
  {
   Write-Host "`nContent Database Name:  $($ContentDb.Name) Size:$($ContentDb.DiskSizeRequired/1MB) MB " -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

Comment: you can check this link : https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/how-to-detect-and-repair-content-db-orphans-objects-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer : http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/05/find-and-delete-unused-sharepoint-databases-from-sql-server.html

for answer

Used powershell and SQL commands to get my result.

Thank You!!